# How to show partial view in datatable child?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I am using the jQuery plugin called datatables. I was trying to use child() to display the contents of a MVC partial view, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the link to the child() documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child()

Here's how I was trying to display the partial view when the user "expands" the table row....

```
// Toggle visibility of tr on or off
    function toggleRow(tr) {
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row - display partial view                           
            row.child('@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/MyPartialView.cshtml")').show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    }
```

Comment: `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/MyPartialView.cshtml")` is razor code that is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view, and you have not passed a model to the partial so its unclear what you expect that to show. Are you wanting to display some additional details associated with the row you have clicked?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks. The MyPartialView.cshtml is just some static HTML. Does this answer your question?

Comment: So what is not working?